# How to get the item in list view using with enter key

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

In my program i want to use key press event in list view.When i press the enter key then only my selected text will print..Can any one please tell me how to use key press event for list view.I tried with  installEventFilter but this method showing non type error.
Given below is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore,QtGui
class List_View(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(List_View, self).__init__(parent)
        self.listview = QtGui.QListView()
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self.listview)
        for i in ['linux', 'windows', 'mac os']:
            model.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem(i))
        self.listview.setModel(model)
        self.listview.entered.connect(self.add_items)
        widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        vlay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(widget)
        vlay.addWidget(self.listview)
        self.resize(400, 200)
    def add_items(self):
      pass #here i need to print particular item in list view

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = List_View()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Do you want the selected item of the QListView to be printed when the enter key is pressed?

Comment: yes sir..but here it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have not read the docs of the [entered](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#entered) signal or you have not understood it, that signal only triggers when the mouse is on the item but for this you must activate the mouse tracking with `self.listview.setMouseTracking(True)`

A simple solution is to use a `QShortcut`:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore,QtGui

class List_View(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(List_View, self).__init__(parent)

        shorcut = QtGui.QShortcut(
            QtGui.QKeySequence(QtCore.Qt.Key_Return),
            self
        )
        shorcut.activated.connect(self.on_enter_pressed)

        self.listview = QtGui.QListView()
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self.listview)
        for i in ['linux', 'windows', 'mac os']:
            model.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem(i))
        self.listview.setModel(model)

        widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        vlay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(widget)
        vlay.addWidget(self.listview)
        self.resize(400, 200)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_enter_pressed(self):
        print("enter press")
        ix = self.listview.selectionModel().currentIndex()
        print(ix.data())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = List_View()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```